# Iterating Through JSON Objects

Tags: php, json, iterator

I apologize for the newbie question, but I'm trying 
I'm trying to iterate through JSON data without listing the specific objects within.

I'm specifying the JSON data first

```
$data = '{
  "question":[{
    "gender":"Both",
    "category":"Finance",
    "question_title":"Will the German Economy Collapse",
    "country":"Lebanon"
    }]
}';
```

I'm then decoding $data

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($data);
```

I'm then trying to iterate through the decoded JSON variable:

```
foreach ($jsonDecoded->question as $object){
    print $object;
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Any pointers as to where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: As the error says: you cannot `print` an object. Try `var_dump($object)` or `print $object->gender`.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't occur to me that the error was due to the actual printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
$data = '{
  "question":[{
    "gender":"Both",
    "category":"Finance",
    "question_title":"Will the German Economy Collapse",
    "country":"Lebanon"
    }]
}';
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($data);
foreach ($jsonDecoded->question as $object){
    print_r ($object);
}
?>
```

like this